# how to detect when MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE is finished

Tags: java, android, motion-detection

I need to detect in my application when user stop moving across a specific view. I'm creating something similar to marque text in my application which can interact while user is touching the view and moving across it. And I need to start scrolling the view after user lifts his finger. As I notices if I move my finger across the view a few seconds and when I lift my finger the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is not called. The last event which I capture is `ACTION_MOVE` . So how can I detect when user lifts his finger after moving across the view a few seconds? Is there some kind of function which can detect that?

Here is the code which I'm using :

```
txt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.e("","event down : "+event.getAction());
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.e("","event up : "+event.getAction());
                if(myTimer!=null){
                    myTimer.cancel();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d("","move");
                // handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                checkX();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show your code. so we can help

Comment: I have same problem with multitouch, after FIRST finger up MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE is sended, then MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP. It's something stupid...

Answer (score 2):

I think the event may be sending an `ACTION_CANCEL` action before the gesture is finished. Or, if it drags outside of the view you're checking, it could be `ACTION_OUTSIDE`.

The best way to confirm/debug this would be to put a `Log.d()` statement in, print the `MotionEvent.getActionMasked()` value, and check to see what actions are being called after your `ACTION_MOVE` event ends.